# Host an image android and get an URL

Tags: android, image, url, hosting

I want to use a service for hosting images in my android application.
The problem is I don't know which one to use. 
I need to get an image from phone's gallery, send that image to server, and return an url for that image.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple and easy to implement abordation will be [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)

Here is a example code:

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data); 
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        } }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        } });
```

You can find more example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

Answer (score 0):

just echo the url of the image and url of the image will be

"localhost/path/image_name.extension_of_image"

Comment: Hi can you please share an example? Thanks